# How to get ItemIndex in Transferred event of Rad ListBox

Tags: telerik

I'm trying to get selected Item Text and value of **RadListBox** in **Transferred** event.

I tried following code:

```
 protected void listbox_Initial_Transferred(object sender, RadListBoxTransferredEventArgs e)
{

           string id =  e.Items[0].Value.ToString();
            string description = e.Items[0].Text.ToString();
 }
```

here i passed "0" as index. Its working fine.

Now i got stuck here to fetch the selected index of Item.

Looking forward for your comments and replies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
 // for single item
 string id = RadListBox1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
 string description = RadListBox1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();

 // for multiple item
 foreach (RadListBoxItem item in RadListBox1.SelectedItems)
 {
     string _id = item.Value.ToString();
     string _description = item.Text.ToString();
 }
```

AS per your sample code, please also try with the below code snippet.

```
// for multiple item
 foreach (RadListBoxItem item in e.Items)
 {
     string _id = item.Value.ToString();
     string _description = item.Text.ToString();
 }
```